# Can Mac App store large icon be different from app icon?

Tags: cocoa, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

On the iOS App Store developers can upload a large app icon for display on the app store through iTunes Connect as part of the process of updating the metadata. As such you can have a  different icon for the app store and for on the actual device--I'm talking here in technical terms, whether one should have a graphically different icon on the app store vs on the device is a different matter altogether.

Going through the process of uploading an app to the Mac App Store I noticed that you cannot upload a large icon and that instead it is pulled out of the bundle. In this case, which icon does it use? Does it just pull one out of the .icns file, e.g. the 512 one? Or can you provide a separate icon along with the main app icon .icns targeted especially for the app store?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload application to iTunes & application icon will automatically appear in iTunes. For MAC application, you need same Icon of 1024*1024 (icon_512x512@2x). if you will not add it in icns file then it will not allow you to upload application to iTunes.